# Fixed Width Page Layout

Tags: css

My manager keeps mentioning fixed width page layouts.  I don't know what he means and don't really want to ask.  He came over to my desk and resized my browser width-ways and mumbled something.  What I'd like to ask is this.

1. What is a fixed width page layout?
2. What is the alternative?
3. Why does it matter?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed width refers to a document styled with a width that is fixed by an absolute unit.

`px` are an example of an absolute unit.

```
width: 100px;
```

One alternative is to make your widths relative such as a `%`.

```
width: 60%;
```

The reason this matters is because different people will have different screen sizes or use their browser in different ways.

Using fixed width means that users on smaller screens, or using their browser minimised,  with have to scroll horizontally rather than the page width adjusting depending on size of their browser window.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is about [fluid design](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Fluid_Design). This basically means that widths on your page are defined using `%` rather than `px`. When you set it up this way the page scale when the viewport gets smaller. Although you have to note that using tables with this can become problematic.

Another way to further achieve this is by using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

One last thing. Why don't you ask your boss what he means?

Comment: Well, I don't want to reveal my ignorance to my boss.

Comment: @SachinKainth hehe. Ok, point taken. However it does show you are willing to learn on the other hand :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using table for your design when you zoom in the canvas you design go out of the box you should use DIV base design this will adjust behalf of your screen.